# почему pending хотя я все сделал асинхронно

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
const mysql2 = require('mysql2/promise')
const config = require('./config')

async function f1(){
    const conn = await mysql2.createConnection(config)
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM `user` where email = "iv@ua"'
    const [rows, field] = await conn.execute(query)
    let q = await rows[0].age
    conn.end()
    return q
}

async function f(){
    return  await f1
}

console.log(f())
```

Comment: Потому что асинхронная функция всегда возвращает промис. Ну и попутно, в приведенном коде функция `f()` не вызывается.

Comment: функция f вызывается ,держу в курсе

Comment: 1) `f().then(console.log)` 2) смущает await в `let q = await rows[0].age`

Comment: Я имел в виду `f1()`, опечатался с телефона.